# Riemann hypothesis prime number theorem

Tags: java

so i am working on the Riemann Hypothesis prime number theorem,
Now my loop is in the method `isPrimeNumber` and the loop is okay because i tested it on a separate class and it worked well..
`primes` is my text area.
My problem here is that i wanted info appended in my text area once i enter any number in my field, but i want when i input 100, it gives me primes numbers from 1-99, but now its giving me numbers to 10,000 - all prime numbers. Any help will be appreciated. Everything is working well.. I tried debugging but couldn't locate the problem, still learning more on debugging.

```
public void run() {
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
        int primeNumbers = 0;
        int allNumbers = 2;
        primes.append("This are the Prime Numbers In " + quantity + " Riemann Hypothesis ");
        while(primeNumbers<quantity){
            if(isPrimeNumber(allNumbers)){
                primes.append(allNumbers + " ");
                primeNumbers++;
            }
            allNumbers++;
        }
```

Comment: [Riemann hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis) is about non-trivial zeta-function zeroes on complex plane. While it's connected to prime numbers, your code seems to me very distant from Riemann hypothesis...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to find prime numbers less than he `quantity` entered. In this case you should not count them, but keep the last primeNumber found to compare to quantity (don't compare count, compare last found)

Comment: @TagirValeev am looping through all the primes .. to a certain number. I understand what the your're saying thanks though. (prime numbers riemann zeta function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're algorithm is now giving you the first 100 prime numbers (which will run up to 541, not 10000). If you want the prime numbers from 1 to 100 instead, change

```
while(primeNumbers<quantity){
```

to

```
while(allNumbers<quantity){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `primeNumbers` is basically counting the number of prime numbers that have been generated. but in your comparison you have `primeNumbers<quantity` checks whether the prime numbers generated is less than the quantity. So your comparison should be `allNumbers<quantity`.

Answer (score 1):

With your code, if you input 100, you are looking for the first 100 primes, if you want to look up to 100 you have to compare quantity with allNumbers, so:

```
while(allNumbers < quantity)
```

If you do so, as soon as you reach 100 you stop checking numbers.